# Deleting the contents of a text file before importing in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have a `SSIS` package which loops through a file location importing data from multiple flat files to one SQL Server table destination. Some rows of data in the file cannot be processed so any that fail, I have sent to a separate flat file destination.

My problem is that if I check the `Overwrite data in the file` box I only receive 3 rows of data out of thousands. If I uncheck the box, then i get a truer picture with over a hundred records that can't be processed for one reason or another. I can't leave it like this as each time the package is run, the contents from the last run are still present.

My question is why is this happening and how can I solve it?

The `Data Flow Task` sits in a `For Each Loop` container, so I suspected that each time the loop is run it overwrites any data sent to the failed rows flat file. However, the data present at the end of the loop is from the first file the loop gets.

Can I script some `SQL` to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every run, before the for loop, delete the file if exists and create a new one, then do not overwrite.

If you want to keep history of previous runs you can suffix the file with a run id or datetime value. If you do this you can also run a clean up to keep only some files either a specific number or within a range of dates.

Comment: Thanks Jayvee, works great. I'm new to SSIS so still finding my way around the range of options on the toolkit!

Comment: Please click the check mark next to this answer to close the question.